# Is it possible when create an abstract class to store basic CRUD and handle them so that service just need to extend

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, interface, abstract

after working on some pet project for beginner. I realize that all of my projects use CRUD as its basic operation for each service. So, I think that I can using Generic to create an interface for CRUD operation, and then using abstract class to implement and provide basic logic for it. Then, with all service in my project, I can let them extend the abstract class and implement the CRUD service and whenever I want to have CRUD operation in one service, I can just call super. from the abstract class instead of write the logical code for it.

```
   

     public interface BasicService<T>{
    1. T add(T model);
    2. T update(T model, int id);
    3. void delete(int id);
    4. T getById(int id);
    }

    @Repository
        public interface BasicRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>{
        }
    public interface CarService extends BasicService<Car>{
    }

        public abstract class  BasicServiceImpl<T> implements BasicService<T>{
        
            private final BasicRepository<T> basicRepository;
            
            public BasicServiceImpl(BasicRepository<T> basicRepository){
                    this.basicRepository = basicRepository;
            }
        
        @Override
            public T getById(int id){
                basicRepository.findById(id)
            }
        
            @Override
            @Transactional
            public ResponseEntity<?> delete(int id){
                this.basicRepository.deleteById(id);
            }
        
            @Override
            public T update(T model, int id){
                return this.basicRepository.save(model);
            }
        
            @Override
            public T add(T model){
                return this.basicRepository.save(model);
            }
    }

    @Service
    public CarServiceImpl extends BasicServiceImpl<Car> implement CarService{
    private CarRepository carRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public CarServiceImpl(CarRepository carRepository){
    super(carRepository);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Car getById(int id){
    return super.getById(id);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Car add(Car model){
    return super.add(model);
    }
    }
```

Comment: In principle, it is possible. But you should also consider whether it's worthy. Composition over inheritance principle exists for a reason. If your motivation is only to eliminate boilerplate code, I woudn't recommend it, as the code will become hard to understand and maintain, specially if new developers participate in the project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @arnaldocan In the first, my ideal is just create an interface for CRUD operation so I don't need to write it again in each service while I have a lot of service that need CRUD operations. So, I've seen some question in stack over flow about this topic and most of the answer is yes.  However, can you please point out the confusion or hard to maintain in the architecture for me ? I'm really confused right now because I think that could be an good architecture.

Comment: @KingNotJoke Ok, let me try to understand better your question then. First, what is the point BasicRepository if it does not add any new method to JpaRepository? In theory, CarService could extend JpaRepository. Second, what is the point of CarService to follow an interface? It should be pretty rare you having any method that manipulate CarService as well as other services, unless you use reflection.

Comment: Third, your solution focus not only on interface (contracts), but in inheritance (implementation), as CarServiceImpl is extending BasicServiceImpl. Inheritance should not to be completely avoided, but is better to not use it when possible. Composition over inheritance is a proposal of the GangOfFour and today is widely accepted. There are different problems with inheritance, you can read the principle to learn more, but shortly, your class can be tempted to have more than one responsibility (single responsibility principle) and the code becomes harder to maintain when you overuse inheritance.

Comment: Every class you will try to maintain, you'll have to open two, sometimes three different files to grasp/remember what is happening in your code. Fourth, it seems to me that you are trying to eliminate boilercode, but at the expense of making your code more complex, which does not pay off. Sometimes, less is more.